How to ignore BUILD files with Bazel?
Currently I am trying to convert an existing cpp project to use the bazel build system. One of my projects dependencies is the library assimp. Currently, I have a git submodule setup that points to the assimp git repository, and in Bazel I am adding this as a local_repository and then using rules_foreign_cc to build assimp from source. My current issue is that assimp has a subdirectory for tools used to contribute to assimp. However one of these tools has a BUILD.bazel file, that triggers a lot of errors from my current Bazel setup that I cannot be asked to fix. I have already tried adding the file to .bazelignore but Bazel doesn't seem to respect it and still attempts to build it anyways. How do I fix this?

.bazelignore is currently not supporting comments - if you have ignore/this/folder # ignore this it will now work

Hello
can you share the content of your .bazelignore and steps you  do to build  your project please ? (bazel command and in which path your run them)
